# Angular passing a variable from a component to a service

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to take a variable and pass it from a method into a service.

from calibration-detail.component.ts

```
private heroID: number;
getTheHeroID() {
    this.heroService.getHero(this.hero.id).subscribe(data =>(this.heroID = data.id));
}
```

to step.service.ts

I'm not sure how to call the variable and store it into another variable.
What I want to do is:

private test: number = CalibrationDetailComponent.heroID //pass into step.service.ts

or

private test: number = CalibrationDetailComponent.getTheHeroID(); //pass into step.service.ts

What's the best way to go about doing this?

step.service.ts

```
import { CalibrationDetailComponent } from './calibration-detail/calibration-detail.component';
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Step } from './step.class';
import { Hero } from './hero.class';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Injectable()
export class StepService {

  hero: Hero;
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private stepsUrl;  // URL to web api
  private heroID: number;

  constructor (private http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute, public heroService: HeroService) { 
    //this.heroService.getHero(+['id']).map(data =>(this.heroID = data.id)); //Get the hero id to know which steps to use

  //defaulting to first one
  if (this.heroID = 1){
   this.stepsUrl = 'api/stepsLiftSensor';
 } else if(this.heroID = 2){
   this.stepsUrl = 'api/BucketSensor';
 } else if(this.heroID = 3){
   this.stepsUrl = 'api/EmptyBucketSensor';
 } else if(this.heroID = 4) {
   this.stepsUrl = 'api/FullBucketSensor';
 }
}

  getSteps(): Observable<Step[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.stepsUrl)
               .map(response => response.json().data as Step[]);
  }

  getStep(id: number): Observable<Step> {
    const url = `${this.stepsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(response => response.json().data as Step);
  }

}
```

calibration-detail.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Hero } from '../hero.class';
import { Step } from '../step.class';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { InMemoryDataService } from '../in-memory-data.service';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { StepService } from '../step.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-calibration-detail',
  templateUrl: './calibration-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calibration-detail.component.css']
})

export class CalibrationDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input()
  hero: Hero;
  step: Step;

  private mainStepText: String = "Test" //Main window
  private statusStepText: String = "Calibration Successfull"; //Status window placeholder
  private labelText: String = "Parking Brake Status \nImpl Lockout Switch \nLift Linkage DC";
  private outputText: String = "Disengaged \nLocked Out \n0%";
  private currentStep: number = 0 //Variable for the current step
  private hideThis: boolean = true;
  private heroID: number;

  constructor(
     private heroService: HeroService,
     private stepService: StepService,
     private route: ActivatedRoute,
     private location: Location,
     private http: Http,
  ) { }


  ngOnInit(): void { 
     this.route.params
       .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
       .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);

     this.route.params
       .switchMap((params: Params) => this.stepService.getStep(+params['id']))
       .subscribe(step => this.step = step);
  }

  goBack() {
    //Goes back to previous step, if there is no previous step it takes you back to location you were at
    if(this.currentStep > 1){
      this.currentStep --;
      this.stepService.getStep(this.currentStep).subscribe(data => (this.mainStepText = data.name));
    } else {
      this.location.back();
    }
  }

  ok() {
    //Placeholder code for now
    this.location.back();
  }

  next() {
    //Assuming there is another step it pulls the next step up, else it says "End of steps"
    if (this.currentStep < 10) { //make sure dont go past number of steps
       this.currentStep ++;
       this.hideThis = false;
       this.stepService.getStep(this.currentStep).subscribe(data => (this.mainStepText = data.name)); //Handles returned observable and sets the data it contains to local variable
  } else {
      this.mainStepText = "End of steps.";
      this.hideThis = true;
    }
  }

  isValid() {
    if (this.currentStep < 1){
      return this.isValid;
    } 
  }

  getTheHeroID() {
    this.heroService.getHero(this.hero.id).subscribe(data =>(this.heroID = data.id));
  }
}
```

hero.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }    from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Hero } from './hero.class';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {

  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

  constructor(private http: Http){ }

  getHeroes(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
               .map(response => response.json().data as Hero[]);
  }

  getHero(id: number): Observable<Hero> {
    const url = `${this.heroesUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(response => response.json().data as Hero);
  }
}
```

Comment: whare are you trying to add above code?

Comment: Can you provide all relevant code pls? The component and the service.

Comment: You are not getting benefits of tree shaking by importing the whole `rxjs` library. You should import from each module specifically. `import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'`. And for the operators: `import 'rxjs/add/operators/switchMap'`

Comment: John is not asking about best practises for going into production with this code, I don't think the bundle size matters here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To pass a value into a service from a component you would do something like:

```
export class SomeService {
    private test: number;

    public setTest(value: number) {
        this.test = value;
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'prefix-some',
    template: `
        <button (click)="sendValueIntoService(1)"></button>
    `
})
export class SomeComponent {

    private test: number;

    constructor(private _someService: SomeService) {}

    sendValueIntoService(value: number) {
        this._someService.setTest(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there is no button click action and It is on a dashboard like so:

    ngOnInit() {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(0, 4));
  }

Comment: <h3>Calibrations</h3>
<div class="grid grid-pad">
  <a *ngFor="let hero of heroes"  [routerLink]="['/detail', hero.id]">
    <div class="module hero">
      <h4>{{hero.name}}</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>

Comment: Where is the data coming from to display on the dashboard? It sounds like you should not be getting data from the component but from the source of that data.

Comment: It should be coming from the hero service I believe.  Which I have added to main post now for clarity.

Comment: What variable from HeroService do you need passed into your service and why. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: When you click 1 of 4 heroes on dashboard, I want to grab the hero.id and pass it to the step.service.  I need to know which one was selected as I'm using a web-api and want to change the url based on which hero was selected.  It will pull up a set up of steps.  Hero1 should pull up Steps1, etc.   I want to pass my custom heroID variable from detail-component to step-service.  Hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: You could use the example here, and call this._someService.setTest(value); when the user clicks 1 of the 4 heroes.

Comment: Ok I'm getting close, I have a problem with your example as right now I have 4 buttons, only 1 html button. <button (click)="gotoClick(1)">{{hero.name}}</button>  With your example I should assign a "1" but then that makes all buttons return 1.  I need a way to have 4 buttons and break each hero into a button.

Answer (score 0):

If we want pass "accounts"(variable having some data from component.ts) to service
We can just passed like below:

first create a new variable in service.ts
service.ts:

```
test : any;
```

component.ts:

```
accounts = [];

constructor(){
    this.service.test = this.accounts
}
```

Finally the new created variable from service will be assigned to the data from accounts