# Create an angular library that accepts dependency

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a component that I would like to turn into an angular library, so I could use it in different projects.

This component uses a service, and it's injected as a dependency in a constructor.

```
  constructor(private myService: SomeService) {
  }
```

How should define this turning this component into a library as a property, so it would accept this service and inject it.

Comment: if it's dependencies are specified in it's own `package.json` you can just import them as normal service.

Comment: @Nicolas, yes, I thought about it. But, would you know, if there is another way, to pass a dependency or not?

Comment: Not really, this is the official way that Angular provide. Is there any limitation that prevent you from using this method ?

Comment: It's just the project that's going to use the library already uses this service, and I thought to just pass it down the library, instead of installing and configuring that same service into the library @Nicolas

Comment: @Nicolas, basically I do want to use the service the angular way, in the constructor, but I want it to come from the user of the library if at all possible.

Comment: Well, you could use a [`setter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44206103/5784924)  to pass this other service to your library, It is possible but I'm not sure it is the right way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take a look at Angular's official documentation on modules and [singleton services](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) and more specifically the `forRoot` method. 
The idea would be to create a module that declares your component. This module would need a `forRoot()` method, which gives ability to pass parameters when importing it in your application module (or any other module).

This question is really broad but the code would look like this (it's an idea and not fully functional):

Your library's module:

```
@NgModule({...})
export class LibraryModule {
  static forRoot(service: MyService): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: LibraryModule,
      providers: [
        {provide: MyService, useClass: service}
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

Your application module that use your library module:

```
import { LibraryModule } from './library/my-module.module';
import { MyService } from './services/my-service.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    LibraryModule.forRoot(MyService)
  ],
})
```

You can have a look at some existing libraries that use this technique. Angular's own router library expect the [routes as a param](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5#routermoduleforroot) of the `forRoot()` method.

Comment: Thanks! Pretty sure this is what I need, just not completely sure about what I pass here forRoot(service: MyService). Do I create a class MyService in the library that describes what's going to get injected? @Guillaume

Comment: I would say: You want a lib with a component that use a service. But said service needs to be "dynamically" passed to the library by the component consumer (the module in which the component will be used). For this, you could create a service in the consumer module, that implements an interface. Said interface would be in the library. So any consumer module could declare its own service that adheres to the library's service interface specifications.

Comment: got it. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome :) I wasn't sure my explanation war clear enough

Comment: It's clear. The funny thing is, it's not quite what I needed after all. And I guess I'm stumped at this point. Maybe I should open another question. Mainly the problem is, is that the main application uses translateModule (ngx-translate) and I want my module (that's separated) to be able to use it as well, the way main app uses it. Probably not clear at all

Comment: Oh yeah, not completely clear then. It changes everything if it's an existing library. You should have a look at dependency injection Angular guide: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: Let me precise this. It's not exactly dependency injection but more how modules import works and how they provide their own services.
A library module like ngx-translate should be added at the top level of the app in your main app module by using `forRoot()`, so their TranslateService is available everywhere. You can see how they did it in the library code: https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/blob/master/projects/ngx-translate/core/src/public_api.ts#L45

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207595/discussion-between-javid-askerov-and-guillaume).