# ANGULAR - Pass variable from Component to Service

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I've been looking at component interactions and passing values from one component to a service, but couldn't find something clear enough.

The premise is simple, I have a variable / value that's coming from an API, and I need that variable to be passed to a service component (which holds the GET request and URL where I need the value).

I was thinking of using EventEmitter, to emit my variable, but then the service doesn't have an HTML to subscribe to it.

Here are some code snippets:

**app.component.ts**

```
private data: any[] = [];

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.apiService.getData().subscribe(response => {
      this.data = response.data;
      
      console.log(this.data.id);
    });
  }
```

**api.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PromptApiService {
  private readonly apiUrl = 'MY_API_URL;

/*I need the id variable from component to access here*/

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  getData(): Observable<> {
    return this.http.get<>(
      `${this.apiUrl}/mydata`,
    );
  }
}
```

I had to remove some of the code for privacy reasons, as this is for a work project, so apologies if the code is minimal.

What would the best aproach be to pass the variable from component to service? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular passing a variable from a component to a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205950/angular-passing-a-variable-from-a-component-to-a-service)

Comment: I think it sort of does answer my question, but same as the solution before, the variable I set in the service.ts file gets an IDE error that it's declared but never read.

Comment: That is not an error, that is warning message, also you need to assign the variably into the method itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just move your `data` variable to your service and then use that in your component(s) by making your service `public`

`api.service.ts`

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PromptApiService {
  private readonly apiUrl = 'MY_API_URL';
  public data: any[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getData(): Observable<> {
    return this.http.get<>(`${this.apiUrl}/mydata`);
  }
}
```

`app.component.ts`

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public promptApiService: PromptApiService)

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.promptApiService.getData().subscribe(response => {
      this.promptApiService.data = response.data;
    });
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`

```
<div *ngIf="promptApiService.data">
  <p>{{ promptApiService.data.id }}</p>
</div>
```

Note: This assumes you are using the default change detection method and not `OnPush`

Answer (score 1):

This kind of things can be a bit difficult when you are starting.

To pass a variable from a component to a service, you have a simple solution:

1. Inside the service `api.service.ts` you can create the variable at the top and the setter:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class PromptApiService {
  private myVariable:string;  // THIS LINE

  private readonly apiUrl = 'MY_API_URL';

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {}

  setMyVariable(myVariable:string):void {  // THIS FUNCTION
    this.myVariable=myVariable;
  }

  getData(): Observable<> {
    ...
  }
}
```

2. Inside `app.component.ts` you instance the service in the constructor and use the setter:

```
constructor( private apiSvc: PromptApiService ) {}   // THIS LINE

ngOnInit(): void {
   this.apiSvc.setMyVariable("HELLO");   // THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: This looks pretty straight forward, however I'm getting an error in the IDE that the variable is declared but never read - in the service.ts file